# What is RowCause in share object

Tags: apex, soql, sharerecord

Can someone please help me to understand when ROWCAUSE is = Manual or Owner or ImplicitChild or Rule.

and if ROWCAUSE is not Manual can we still delete shareObject from apex if yes then how because I was getting an error while querying and deleting shareobject without
Rowcause = manual I was getting an error INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY

Thank you so much in anticipation!

Comment: I think this question should be reopened, as it contains a better answer than the original

Comment: That's not really the purpose of reopening. The questions are linked, which is valuable. There isn't much blowback from asking a duplicate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

RowCause is the *reason* why the share exists. There are a large number of reasons why shares may exist. A non-exhaustive list of standard shares are as follows:

- Owner - The user in OwnerId
- Manual - A manual share from the UI or code
- Rule - A sharing rule created this entry
- ImplicitChild - A parent record shares access with its children
- ImplicitParent - A child record shares access with its parent
- ImplicitPerson - Person Account Sharing (?)
- Team - The user is a member of a team (AccountTeam, OpportunityTeam)
- Territory - The user is in a given territory
- TerritoryManual - The record was manually shared to a territory
- Territory2AssociationManual - The record was manually assigned to a territory
- TerritoryRule - A territory rule shared the record
- Territory2Forecast - Territory forecasting calculations shared the record

Only manual shares and [custom shares](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_apex_sharing_reasons.htm&type=5) can be created, modified, and deleted, although some shares can also have their AccessLevel fields modified (e.g. Team sharing entries). All of the others are generated by the system based on sharing calculations. For example, the user specified by OwnerId automatically gains a sharing entry for Owner. You can't remove this entry because they own the record. Likewise, you can't add a new Owner this way. Instead, you would change the OwnerId field, and the system recalculates the Owner sharing entries based on that change.

I may have a few descriptions not quite right, and there may be some missing options; I simply pulled these values from the describe for the RowCause field and extrapolated based on my knowledge of Salesforce. There's a lot of information about these various sharing settings in the documentation, but they're spread out across many topics. You'll want to do more research on it.

For anything other than manual shares, you must correct the situation that caused the share. For example, if the share reason is Team, then you must delete the appropriate AccountTeamMember or OpportunityTeamMember record.

Comment: You are amazing, thank you so much!

Comment: I hate to say this, because I think @sfdxfox is amazing, but I think the description  here about implicitParent and ImplicitChild is backwards. It is confusing and a super easy thing to get wrong because it really makes no logical sense.

Comment: @SaraMorgan We're all human and make mistakes, even the "great" sfdcfox. That said, I found it in the docs, and you're right. I'll edit this for future visitors. Thanks for calling it out.